# Prop. score matching with subsequent time-varying exposure

Tags: propensity-scores, time-varying-covariate

I'm running basic propensity score matched cohorts and running a typical "intention-to-treat" analyses in patients with dementia, estimating mainly effects of treatment on e.g. mortality. Patients are matched on incident drug usage at time of dementia diagnosis (entry to study). However, I have also data on yearly usage AFTER dementia is diagnosed, however I have never ran across a study that would take the PS matched cohort (matched at start of the study) and then take into account that people can transfer from exposed to unexposed and vice-versa after the start time. Is this reasoning flawed and can even typical methods like cox or flexible parametric models be used? Or does one have to use marginal structural models with weighting? I'd like to keep the comparability of the exposed-unexposed cohorts achieved with PS matching with the ability to take into account time-varying nature of the exposure assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weighting for marginal structural models would be the ideal technique here. You could simply perform the weighting in the matched sample to retain the benefits of matching at the first time point and then use the weights to address time-varying confounding at later time points. You could also just forget the matching and use weighting entirely. Weighting also ensures the comparability of the exposed/unexposed groups at the first time point (and thereafter), so unless you have a particularly good reason to be so attached to matching over weighting, eschewing the matching entirely is a valid option. Given that you have a survival outcome, you should look into marginal structural survival models.

There are other techniques to address time-varying confounding. You could use longitudinal targeted maximum likelihood estimation (LTMLE), which is multiply-robust and uses flexible models to model the transition into exposure and the intermediate and final outcomes. The `ltmle` R package makes this possible. The literature on sequential/dynamic treatments would be a place to start.

Comment: Thank you Noah! One follow-up question - is MSM still the way to go if the only variable that is time-varying is the exposure? I have no information on the confounders of the treatment after the baseline time, i have only information on whether patients started or stopped using medication in yearly intervals. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, because you still need to account for the fact that baseline confounders affect future treatment selections. For example, even though the first treatment is as-if randomized because of the matching, by the last year, only people with severe risk moved to one of the treatment arms. An MSM accounts for that, but other methods do too, like simply regressing the outcome on the treatments and covariates. That said, if unmeasured intermediate outcomes cause selection into treatment, you have unmeasured confounding that could bias your results.

Comment: Just to clarify based on - "like simply regressing the outcome on the treatments and covariates" - even a Cox model in the whole cohort with time-varying exposure and adjustment for baseline covariates would be better than PS matching?

Comment: It would be better than PS matching alone, but you could also do it in the PS matched dataset to add some robustness. If people die before they can take future treatments, though, that needs to be accounted for. If not, then a regular Cox model with covariates in the matched or unmatched sets should be basically fine (other than functional form issues and unmeasured confounding).

Comment: Ok, I'll go for the MSM with stabilized weights, and compare how the models fared in just basic adjustment vs the weighted one. Overall - big thanks.